# Sudo giving dyld problem. Help for a beginner

Tags: terminal, sudo

I am new to using a macbook terminal. Initially when I used the terminal for working on Raspberry Pi everything was great. But now when I try to use the terminal and type
 sudo
 it keeps giving a dyld message. And also rejects my commands. The message is :

dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid

Password:

what do I do? And why has this message started appearing all of a sudden? 
Can anyone give a step by step guide on stopping this
Thanks a lot:)

Comment: What do you mean it rejects your commands? Does that give you an error message too? That's certainly odd—try running `env | grep '^DYLD'` and see what the output is.

Comment: Did you set DYLD_ environment ?

Comment: by reject i mean that it keeps displaying the dyld_environment message everytime I try to use sudo.

Comment: I typed the command and the output was:DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/X11/lib:/usr/lib::

Comment: no I haven't set the environment.

Comment: Add the information about your DYLD variable within your original question (\[edit] button).

Answer (score 1):

On the short term,
within a `Terminal` enter:

```
unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and check that:

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

is working.

Your description let think of an installer which modified your working
environment in closed relationship with the X11 environment.

To further analyze where this problem is coming, within a `Terminal` search which initialisation file might be working on this environment variable:

```
grep DYLD ${HOME}/.profile ${HOME}/.bash_profile ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

If you are using anything else than `sh` or `bash` as your working shell,
search inside the equivalent initialisation files.